# Why I have the same content in 4 loops? WP

Tags: wordpress

I have 4 divs under my main navi menu, I wont to display in every single div recent posts from single category. I use this code, but in every div I have the same content (I changed the category-ID).

```
<?php // display a list of recent case studies
        // instantiate an instance of WP_Query as a variable $recentPosts
        $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
        // get last 10 posts from category 7 (case studies)
        $recentPosts->query('showposts=4&amp;cat=4');
        // utilize two methods to get at template tags (below)
        while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) :
        $recentPosts->the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="slide" ><a href="<?php // bump out what we need courtesy of template tags
     the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2><?php echo excerpt(20); ?></a></div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 6, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'category' => 3 );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
?> 
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```